# How to conditionally aggregate a value in a select statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, aggregate-functions

I need to conditionally be able to get the minimum date value in a sub-select, however I am unable to do this because the query expects me to include the value in my group by statement.

I have a select statement which selects from a sub-select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  Begin_Date
FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT 
    CASE WHEN (id IS NOT NULL) THEN MIN (start_date)
         ELSE initial_date 
    END AS Begin_Date
  FROM ... 
)
GROUP BY
  Begin_Date
```

The above query will not allow me to group by the `begin_date` because of the MIN aggregation I have in the sub-select, however I still need a way to get the minimum `start date` if the `id` is not null, or the non aggregated `initial_date` if the `id` is null.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Use two separate queries, one for the null IDs, another for the non-null IDs. Then combine them with UNION.

Answer (score 0):

> in the sub-select, however I still need a way to get the minimum `start_date` if the `id` is not null, or the non aggregated `initial_date` if the `id` is null.

It looks like a *window* `min` would do what you want. Assuming MySQL 8.0:

```
select begin_date, ...
from (
    select case 
        when id is null then initial_date
        else min(start_date) over() 
    end as begin_date
    from ...
) t
group by begin_date
```

The subquery does not aggregate, but computes the new `begin_date` based on the rules you described; then you can `group by` in the outer query.

Side note: on null `id`s, this gives you the earliest `start_date` over *the whole table*; you can add `partition by` in the `over()` clause to restrict the range of rows to search.